# Failed to start because of 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, emf

I don't understand why is this showing since I have wrote the @EnableJpaRepository already

AppStarter

```
package com.servers;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses=com.servers.server1.dao.LinieDao.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ServersApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ServersApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

App proprieties

```
    spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ServersDataBase
spring.datasource.username=postgre
spring.datasource.password=22ALGORITMul!(($
```

Controler

```
package com.servers.server1.controler;

import com.servers.server1.models.Linie;
import com.servers.server1.service.LinieService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by OGKey on 07-Jan-18.
 */

@RestController
public class LinieControler {

    @Autowired
    private LinieService linieService;


    @RequestMapping(value="/show_linii")
    @CrossOrigin
    public List<Linie> getAll(){
        return linieService.getAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/linia")
    @CrossOrigin
    public String getByNr(@RequestParam("id") String nr){
        return linieService.getLinieByNr(nr).toString();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/adauga")
    @CrossOrigin
    public void addLinie(){
        Random r= new Random();
        linieService.addLinie(String.valueOf(r.nextInt(10)),r.nextInt(20));
    }
}
```

Repository

```
package com.servers.server1.dao;

import com.servers.server1.models.Linie;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface LinieDao extends CrudRepository<Linie,Long>{
    public Linie findByNr(String nr);
}
```

Model

```
package com.servers.server1.models;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table

public class Linie {
    @Column(name="Nr")
    private String numar;
    @Column(name="Plecare1")
    private int[] plecare1;
    @Column(name="Plecare2")
    private int[] plecare2;
    @Column(name="Delay")
    private int delay;

    public Linie(){
        plecare1= new int[12];
        plecare2= new int[12];
    }

    public Linie(String numar){
        this();
        this.numar=numar;
        defaultIt();
    }

    public Linie(int delay){
        this();
        this.delay=delay;
        defaultIt();
    }

    public Linie(String numar, int delay){
        this();
        this.numar=numar;
        this.delay=delay;
        defaultIt();
    }

    public void defaultIt(){
        for(int i=0; i<12; i++){
            plecare1[i]=i;
            plecare2[i]=i+2;
        }
    }

    public String getNumar() {
        return numar;
    }

    public void setNumar(String numar) {
        this.numar = numar;
    }

    public int[] getPlecare1() {
        return plecare1;
    }

    public void setPlecare1(int[] plecare1) {
        this.plecare1 = plecare1;
    }

    public int[] getPlecare2() {
        return plecare2;
    }

    public void setPlecare2(int[] plecare2) {
        this.plecare2 = plecare2;
    }

    public int getDelay() {
        return delay;
    }

    public void setDelay(int delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String show;
        show="Linia "+numar+" are "+delay+" intarziere.";
        return show;
    }
}
```

Service

```
package com.servers.server1.service;

import com.servers.server1.dao.LinieDao;
import com.servers.server1.models.Linie;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


@Service
public class LinieService {

    @Autowired
    LinieDao db;

    public Linie getLinieByNr(String nr){
        return db.findByNr(nr);
    }

    public List<Linie> getAll(){
        List<Linie> linii= new ArrayList<Linie>();
        for(Linie linie: db.findAll()){
            linii.add(linie);
        }
        return linii;
    }

    public void updateDelay(String nr, int delay){

        for(Linie linie: db.findAll()){
            if(linie.getNumar().equals(nr)){
                linie.setDelay(delay);
                db.save(linie);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addLinie(String nr, int delay){
        try{
            db.save(new Linie(nr, delay));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void removeLinie(String nr){
        db.delete(db.findByNr(nr));
    }
}
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>servers</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Servers</name>
    <description>Comunicating Servers</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.shell</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-shell-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.M2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

Log

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\java" -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Didea.launcher.port=7541 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\rt.jar;H:\Faculta\An 4\Sem 1\IOM\Servers\target\classes;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\apache\cxf\cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs\3.1.11\cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs-3.1.11.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.1.11\logback-classic-1.1.11.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.1.11\logback-core-1.1.11.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.25\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\log4j-over-slf4j\1.7.25\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.17\snakeyaml-1.17.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\apache\cxf\cxf-spring-boot-autoconfigure\3.1.11\cxf-spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.11.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\apache\cxf\cxf-rt-transports-http\3.1.11\cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.11.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\apache\cxf\cxf-core\3.1.11\cxf-core-3.1.11.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\woodstox\woodstox-core-asl\4.4.1\woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\woodstox\stax2-api\3.1.4\stax2-api-3.1.4.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\xmlschema\xmlschema-core\2.2.1\xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\apache\cxf\cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs\3.1.11\cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.11.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\javax\ws\rs\javax.ws.rs-api\2.0.1\javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.2\javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\apache\cxf\cxf-rt-rs-client\3.1.11\cxf-rt-rs-client-3.1.11.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.1.0.Final\validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\shell\spring-shell-starter\2.0.0.M2\spring-shell-starter-2.0.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\shell\spring-shell-core\2.0.0.M2\spring-shell-core-2.0.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-validation-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\jline\jline\3.4.0\jline-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\jline\jline-terminal-jna\3.4.0\jline-terminal-jna-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna\4.2.2\jna-4.2.2.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\jline\jline-terminal\3.4.0\jline-terminal-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\shell\spring-shell-standard\2.0.0.M2\spring-shell-standard-2.0.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\shell\spring-shell-standard-commands\2.0.0.M2\spring-shell-standard-commands-2.0.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\shell\spring-shell-shell1-adapter\2.0.0.M2\spring-shell-shell1-adapter-2.0.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\shell\spring-shell-jcommander-adapter\2.0.0.M2\spring-shell-jcommander-adapter-2.0.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\shell\spring-shell-table\2.0.0.M2\spring-shell-table-2.0.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring4\2.1.6.RELEASE\thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf\2.1.6.RELEASE\thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\ognl\ognl\3.0.8\ognl-3.0.8.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\unbescape\unbescape\1.1.0.RELEASE\unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\nz\net\ultraq\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-layout-dialect\1.4.0\thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\groovy\groovy\2.4.13\groovy-2.4.13.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\5.3.6.Final\hibernate-validator-5.3.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.1.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.4\classmate-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.8.10\jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.8.0\jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.8.10\jackson-core-2.8.10.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\postgresql\postgresql\9.4.1212.jre7\postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\8.5.23\tomcat-embed-el-8.5.23.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\1.13.6.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.25\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.0.0.M7\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.0.0.M7.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-aop-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.13\aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jdbc\8.5.23\tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-juli\8.5.23\tomcat-juli-8.5.23.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.0.12.Final\hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.0.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.21.0-GA\javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec\1.1.1\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.0.Final\jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.1.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\javax.transaction-api\1.2\javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\1.11.9.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-aspects-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\OGKey\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.4.01\xml-apis-1.4.01.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.servers.ServersApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.9.RELEASE)

2018-01-07 16:46:41.648  INFO 13752 --- [           main] com.servers.ServersApplication           : Starting ServersApplication on DESKTOP-LG7Q1UV with PID 13752 (started by OGKey in H:\Faculta\An 4\Sem 1\IOM\Servers)
2018-01-07 16:46:41.651  INFO 13752 --- [           main] com.servers.ServersApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-01-07 16:46:42.058  INFO 13752 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7d68ef40: startup date [Sun Jan 07 16:46:42 EET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-01-07 16:46:43.178  INFO 13752 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.shell.SpringShellAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.shell.SpringShellAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$90afdbd8] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-01-07 16:46:43.201  INFO 13752 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'conversionService' of type [org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-01-07 16:46:43.385  WARN 13752 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'linieControler': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'linieService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'linieService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'db'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'linieDao': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#433ffad1' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#433ffad1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
2018-01-07 16:46:43.397  INFO 13752 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-01-07 16:46:43.472 ERROR 13752 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field db in com.servers.server1.service.LinieService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have read the entire stackoverflow already.Did not managed to create a bean neither to find the appConfig.xml file, dependencies are all there and also tried different approaches from just @EnableJpaRepository

Please help.

Comment: Could you show your Gradle/Maven file? Looks like some wrong with dependencies.

Comment: I have updated the question with pom.xml

Comment: For starters stop mixing Spring Boot versions (1.5.9 and 2.0.0.M2). Second use the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency instead of manually defined `spring-data-commons` and `spring-data-jpa` dependencies. And remove the `version` attribute for the `spring-boot-starter` dependencies those are already managed by the inclusion of the parent.

Comment: I have done everything you said, still the same error

Answer (score 0):

you have defined spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency twice in pom. and maybe local repo have corrupted hibernate-entity-* jars. remove maven  local repo and try again.

Comment: I have deleted the second dependency declaration from proprieties, also deleted the maven local repo, still the same problem

Comment: Help anyone? pls

Answer (score 0):

In your `ServersApplication` class also remove the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation.
It is already included in `@SpringBootApplication`
You can read more in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html)

> The @SpringBootApplication annotation is equivalent to using
>   @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan with their
>   default attributes

To go one step further you can actually very easy check what beans are created with what dependencies. There are two ways. Either by using the `ListableBeanFactory` interface or spring boot actuator. Check [this tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-show-all-beans) on how to do that. If you go for the actuator solution you can also have a look on the documentation of [endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found the reason of why my app was not working. The entityManagerFactory works with an `@Id` base column in the table of your declared data base. I did not needed and so I did not use it, but after adding it back it worked